# How to enable anonymous login in SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: anonymous-authentication

How do I enable anonymous login in SharePoint Server 2010?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

answer is here

[enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 2):

Or, in Powershell:

```
$wa = get-spwebapplication http://{url}
$zone = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUrlZone]::Extranet
$i = $wa.IisSettings[$zone]
$i.AllowAnonymous = $true
$wa.Update()
$wa.ProvisionGlobally()

$w = Get-SPWeb http://{url}
$w.AnonymousState = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb+AnonymousState]::On
$w.Update()

$l = $w.Lists["Comments"]
$l.AnonymousPermMask64 = {BasePermissions as appropriate}
```

Comment: Just to be safe, it is a good idea to use Start-SPAssignment / Stop-SPAssignment with disposable SharePoint objects:
Start-SPAssignment -Global <NEWLINE>
$w = Get-SPWeb http://{url} <NEWLINE>
#more code here <NEWLINE>
Stop-SPAssignment -Global

Comment: When processing many SPWeb's, I agree. Most dev's that I teach find the SPAssignment model confusing, so I leave that out of snippets that I post. [Closing the PowerShell console will clean-up memory ;)]

Comment: Yeah thats what i ment with just to be safe. You never know where the code is going to run, and you never now when your IT pro will close that console again ;-) Global assignment collections is simple, but SemiGlobal can get confusing when you start piping it to Get-SPWeb :-)

Comment: The AnonymousState enum is written as `[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb+WebAnonymousState]::On` in 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can check out an article [here](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/asphostcentralcom_aspnet_host/archive/2010/06/30/Sharepoint-Foundation-_2800_WSS_2900_-2010-Hosting-_3A003A00_-How-to-enable-Anonymous-Access-in-Sharepoint-2010.aspx)